# How to get date after n number of days in a date range?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a start date which is 3/Sep/2019 and end date 10/Sep/2019.

I want to get the date after 4 days from the starting date. So if my starting date is 3/sep/2019 I want to get 7/Sep/2019 but not 12/sep/2019 since this date comes after my end date.

How can I achieve this?

So far I'm getting dates after n number of dates like this:

```
  var days = 7;
  var date = new Date();
  var res = date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  date = new Date(res);
  alert(date);
```

Comment: Please explain your need again.

Comment: You've said `4` days but the dates that you've mentioned are `5` days apart.

Comment: @Titus, my bad. I've edited the question with correct information.

Comment: You want exactly 4 days more? or any random between 4 days after initial and before ending date?

Comment: @cg7, the number 4 can be any number. I've just used for explaining the question a bit more.

Comment: It is still not clear. Are you trying to increase the start day by a specific interval (once or multiple times) to get a data that is before the end data ?

Comment: i get that the number is any number, my question was, if you pick lets say number 3, so 3 days, you want the EXACT date after 3 days? or any date between start-date+3 and end date? my question is because you wrote "I want to get dates after 4 days from the starting date." since you wrote "dates" im getting it can be the one after 5 days or the one after 6 days  as long as it doesnt surpass the end date

Comment: Is your end date a string or a Date object? If the latter, you can compare your new date with end date using `>` or `<`

Comment: @cg7, I've edited the question again. I want only one date after exactly 4 days from starting date.

Answer (score 0):

```
var days = 7;
var date = new Date();
var res = date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
```

This is how you get a day 7 days after the date you already have. It wraps to the next month when appropriate as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function I wrote below:

```js
function getFutureDate(daysAhead) {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysAhead);
  return date
}

const fourDays = getFutureDate(4)
console.log(fourDays)
```

Comment: This only returns a date after 4 days from current date. What I have is range of dates and I want dates between that range 4 days apart.

Comment: perhaps you should fix your question as it is completely unclear what you wrote originally and your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var days = 4;
var date = new Date(3/9/2019);
var res = new Date(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
alert(res.toISOString().substring(0, 10););
```

Comment: Please add some information about your solution.